# Values which change over time or every second

Tags: mysql, backend, rdbms

Lets say we need to update our values in db every second for game like scenarios, where resources change at some rate of time. 
Ex: 5 gold/sec
I thought of storing timestamps and calculating on demand. But then scenarios like warehouse can hold only x amount scenario, Other x amount increase or decrease at any point of time scenarios.
Including cases where the rate changes at different points of time as well.

How do we handle such scenarios in the backend?

Comment: You can use the Event Scheduler to execute a query periodically.

Comment: This would be very inefficient and can't be done to all rows of a table

Comment: What you're trying to do is necessarily inefficient. Maybe you shouldn't be doing it in the database in the first place, but do something in the application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating a database every second is inefficient, so using timestamps and calculating on demand is a good idea.

If a warehouse has a storage limit, then when you calculate that a warehouse should now have 5000 gold, but it only has space for 1000, you only set it to 1000.

If someone sends you gold (increases at a random time), you first calculate what the warehouse should be at before you add the new resources.

If someone steals gold from you (decrease at a random time), you do the same thing.

Essentially, whenever the amount of gold is accessed, you update it to be current to the current time based on the last time it was updated.

For example:

- 1:00 - I log off at 100/500 gold, gold generates at 100/hr (last_updated: 1:00)
- 2:00 - Someone else logs in and sends 200 gold to my village (last_updated: 1:00)
- 3:00 - The resources arrive at my village, so we calculate the new gold storage: 100 for the hr production + 200 from sender for a total of 400 now (last_updated: 3:00)
- 4:00 - Someone sends a raid on my village (last_updated: 3:00)
- 5:00 - Nothing
- 6:00 - The attacker steals 200 gold from me, so we calculate new gold storage: 300 for hr production, but 300 + 400 > 500, so we only have 500/500 at this time. The attack takes 200, so -200 for a result of 400/500. (last_updated: 6:00)
- 6:30 - I log back in to see my gold at 450/500 since 30 mins have passed

Example where rate changes (like if your production was upgraded while offline):

- 0/1000 gold, 100/hr, I have something that will complete in 2 hr that will increase production to 200/hr
- You log back in 5 hrs later (or someone steals, or someone gives) and it will now be 100 * 2 + 200 * 3 = 800/1000

You will know the last timestamp and current time

If any pending events don't change the rate, you can treat the whole inactive time as the same rate

If the rate did change, you need to know at what time(s) did the rate change.  Then you have many segments of differing rates: If the example starts at 1:00, then at 3:00 you know the production was changed, so you can have 2 segments: 1:00 ~ 3:00, 3:00 ~ 6:00 (you split the inactive time segment by the time(s) the rates change).  You assign a rate to each segment, and then you can calculate the gold increase in each segment separately and sum them together.  Again, you do this whenever the gold value is accessed.

Comment: What about cases where the rate also changes at different times?

Comment: i added an example

Comment: oh the actual rate changing.  I'll add one for that too

Comment: Rate of change is also similar. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I added for if the rate changes while you're offline, hopefully, it's not too confusing.

Comment: My lines of thought were similar. Once you put them down on paper it becomes apparent! Thank you!